# qTip2 form values won't load

Tags: jquery, qtip2

I have a hidden div with a form, which is displayed in a qTip2 when a button(.acceptAppButton) is clicked. It's important to note that there are multiple such buttons, each with a numerical ID. On click, in addition to showing the qtip, i'd like to populate a hidden field in the form (name=app_id) with the ID of the button that was clicked. However, when I try to dynamically change the value of the hidden form field, the qTip loads an empty form.

If I remove the class hidden in the debugger I can see that the original hidden form HAS been correctly populated, but the qtip is not.

HTML:

```
<div class="hidden acceptanceMessageTooltip">
<form method="POST" action="SITEURL" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <input class="hidden" name="app_id" type="text">
    <textarea placeholder="Message" rows="3" name="acceptance_message" cols="50"></textarea>
    <input class="btn-med" value="Send" type="submit">
</form>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
    $('.acceptAppButton').click(function() {
       var appId=$(this).attr('id');
       $(".acceptanceMessageTooltip input:text[name=app_id]").val(appId);
       $('.acceptAppButton').qtip('option', 'content.text',
       $('.acceptanceMessageTooltip').html());
    });

$('.acceptAppButton').qtip({
    content: $('.acceptanceMessageTooltip').html(),
    show: {event: 'click'},
    hide: {event: 'unfocus'},
    style: {classes: 'qtip-bootstrap'},
    position: {
        my: 'top center',
        at: 'bottom center'
    }
});
```

Comment: anyone willing to answer?